# What does "CALLBACK" in a Windows API function declaration mean?

Tags: windows, winapi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [What does a “CALLBACK” declaration in C do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530504/what-does-a-callback-declaration-in-c-do)

The prototype of a WindowProc() function is this

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd,UINT message , WPARAM wParan, LPARAM lParam);
```

But I've never come across the CALLBACK keyword, I only know that a callback function is one you pass a pointer to another function to, so what exactly is this CALLBACK over here? and what does it do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's #defined as `__stdcall`, because that's what the Win32 API assumes about callback functions. It's a calling convention - it describes the way a  function call is arranged on the low level - how are parameters arranged on the CPU stack, and suchlike. The assumptions about the expected stack layout (i. e. the calling convention) must match between the caller and the callee, otherwise all kinds of fun consequences might ensue.

Historically, on the Intel CPUs there were multiple calling conventions; more if you count non-Microsoft compilers. Even more if you count languages other than C[++] that are capable of calling and getting called by Windows API. Making sure your Windows API callbacks are explicitly marked as `__stdcall` to match the WinAPI expectation is a good practice. In some cases, depending on compiler and settings, `__stdcall` is the default calling convention (i. e. you can safely omit CALLBACK), but not always.

Back in Win16, CALLBACK was defined as `far pascal`. That's even less likely to be the default for user functions, especially in a C program. The fact that callbacks were assumed to have a Pascal calling convention was an historical artifact. It also worked as a microoptimization.

Comment: what exactly is _stdcall? the way LRESULT is the return type, what is _stdclall? what position does it occupy in the decleration? And, could u put it a little simply- what does it callback to?

Comment: __stdcall denotes a [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention), one of many possible. A callback is a technique where API calls your function instead of vice versa. To do that properly, the API needs to know the calling convention that your function follows.

Comment: how can we change the calling convention? And does the winproc function also somehow follow the convention (doesnt that make sense, becoz we're telling windows which convention to follow, which means that the winproc is connected to the convention)? Sorry for the array of questions, i'm jst not completely satisfied

Comment: You can change the calling convention on your functions. Look up keywords __cdecl, __thiscall, __fastcall. HOWEVER, if the function will be called by code that's not yours (i. e. by Windows code), the convention that you declare it with has to match the convention it will be called with. Which is __stdcall, because that's what Windows assumes. In Windows header files, __stdcall has been, for your convenience, aliased as CALLBACK.

Comment: For completeness' sake, it should be noted that `CALLBACK` has no relevance anymore in code compiled for x64 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62746886/why-is-the-stdcall-calling-convention-ignored-in-x64)