# How does a C function callback work?

Tags: c, tapi

I'm a bit confused with this definition in an example provided by microsoft using TAPI in Windows Mobile 5.0. What does `CALLBACK` do in this case? What is the purpose of it?

`BOOL CALLBACK DialingProc (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);`

The implementation looks the same `BOOL and CALLBACK`.

```
BOOL CALLBACK DialingProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
   //Some code here...
}
```

I've been following http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ which is great but haven't really seen anything in regards to this... Also did a couple searches but no luck- maybe i don't know what i'm searching for here?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're actually asking here?

Comment: @psmears Updated my question.

Comment: Ah, I see, you're asking about CALLBACK - which is quite tricky to search for, as you tend to get a lot of irrelevant hits about callbacks in general. Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530504/what-does-a-callback-declaration-in-c-do) provide the answers you need?

Comment: @psmears I didn't find this one! Thanks. I got an answer here so I guess i'll keep the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CALLBACK` is `#define`d as `__stdcall`
stdcall is a calling convention that determines how arguments are passed. WinAPI uses this very often. 
See [What does "CALLBACK" in a Windows API function declaration mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066202/what-does-callback-in-a-windows-api-function-declaration-mean)