# Why is the __stdcall calling convention ignored in x64?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, x86-64, calling-convention

I know what the differences between `__cdecl` and `__stdcall` are, but I'm not quite sure as to why `__stdcall` is ignored by the compiler in x64 builds.

The functions in the following code

```
int __stdcall stdcallFunc(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f, int g)
{
    return a + b + c + d + e + f + g;
}

int __cdecl cdeclFunc(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f, int g)
{
    return a + b + c + d + e + f + g;
}

int main()
{
    stdcallFunc(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
    cdeclFunc(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);

    return 0;
}
```

have enough parameters to exceed the available CPU registers. Therefore, some arguments must be passed via the stack. I'm not fluent in assembly but I noticed some differences between x86 and x64 assembly.

**x64**

```
main    PROC
$LN3:
        sub     rsp, 72                             ; 00000048H
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+48], 7
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+40], 6
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+32], 5
        mov     r9d, 4
        mov     r8d, 3
        mov     edx, 2
        mov     ecx, 1
        call    ?stdcallFunc@@YAHHHHHHHH@Z          ; stdcallFunc
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+48], 7
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+40], 6
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+32], 5
        mov     r9d, 4
        mov     r8d, 3
        mov     edx, 2
        mov     ecx, 1
        call    ?cdeclFunc@@YAHHHHHHHH@Z                ; cdeclFunc
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 72                             ; 00000048H
        ret     0
main    ENDP
```

**x86**

```
_main   PROC
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp
        push    7
        push    6
        push    5
        push    4
        push    3
        push    2
        push    1
        call    ?stdcallFunc@@YGHHHHHHHH@Z          ; stdcallFunc
        push    7
        push    6
        push    5
        push    4
        push    3
        push    2
        push    1
        call    ?cdeclFunc@@YAHHHHHHHH@Z                ; cdeclFunc
        add     esp, 28                             ; 0000001cH
        xor     eax, eax
        pop     ebp
        ret     0
_main   ENDP
```

1. The first 4 arguments are, as expected, passed via registers in x64.
2. The remaining arguments are put on the stack in the same order as in x86.
3. Contrary to x86, in x64 we don't use `push` instructions. Instead we reserve enough stack space at the beginning of `main` and use `mov` instructions to add the arguments to the stack.
4. In x64, no stack cleanup is happening after both `call`s, but at the end of `main`.

This brings me to my questions:

1. Why does x64 use `mov` rather than `push`? I assume it's just more efficient and wasn't available in x86.
2. Why is there no stack cleanup after the `call` instructions in x64?
3. What's the reason that Microsoft chose to ignore `__stdcall` in x64 assembly?
   From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/cpp/stdcall?view=vs-2019):

   > On ARM and x64 processors, __stdcall is accepted and ignored by the compiler

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/Cah7Cf) is the example code and assembly.

Comment: A new calling convention was created for x64, and there was no good reason to intentionally create two incompatible versions, so there's only one.  You can read about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Microsoft_x64_calling_convention).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 1. Why does x64 use `mov` rather than `push`? I assume it's just more efficient and wasn't available in x86.

That is not the reason. Both of these instructions also exist in x86 assembly language.

The reason why your compiler is not emitting a `push` instruction for the x64 code is probably because it must adjust the stack pointer directly anyway, in order to create 32 bytes of "shadow space" for the called function. See [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Microsoft_x64_calling_convention) (which was provided by @NateEldredge) for further information on "shadow space".

Allocating 32 bytes of "shadow space" with `push` instructions would take 4 64-bit `push` instructions, but only one `sub` instruction. That is why it prefers to use the `sub` instruction. Since it is using the `sub` instruction anyway to create 32 bytes of shadow space, there is no penalty to change the operand of the `sub` instruction from 32 to 72, which allocates 72 bytes of memory on the stack, which is enough to also pass 3 parameters on the stack (the other 4 are passed in CPU registers).

I don't understand why it is allocating 72 bytes on the stack, though, as, according to my calculcations, it only has to be 56 bytes (32 bytes of "shadow space" and 24 bytes for the 3 parameters that are passed on the stack). Possibly, the compiler is reserving those extra 16 bytes for local variables or for exception handling, which may be optimized away when compiler optimizations are active.

---

> 2. Why is there no stack cleanup after the call instructions in x64?

There is stack cleanup after the call instructions. This is what the line

`add rsp, 72`

does.

However, for some reason (probably increased performance), the x64 compiler only performs the cleanup at the end of the calling function, instead of after every function call. This means that with the x64 compiler, all function calls share the same stack space for their parameters, whereas with the x86 compiler, the stack space is allocated and cleaned up at every function call.

---

> 3. What's the reason that Microsoft chose to ignore __stdcall in x64 assembly?

The keywords `_stdcall` and `_cdecl` specify 32-bit calling conventions. That's why they are not relevant for 64-bit programs (i.e. x64). On x64, there is only the [standard calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Microsoft_x64_calling_convention) and the extended [`__vectorcall`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Microsoft_vectorcall) calling convenction.

Comment: Yes, doing stack cleanup once on function exit is obviously better for code-size and performance than doing it between calls.  It also lets the compiler clean up locals *and* child shadow space / stack-arg space at the same time.

Comment: The "standard" Windows x64 calling convention is called x64 `__fastcall`, I think.  MSVC's `-Gv` option makes `__vectorcall` the default; I haven't tested if `__fastcall` can override back to not passing vectors in XMM regs.

Comment: _"There is stack cleanup after the call instructions"_ I've seen that one at the end of the main function. I was wondering why there is no cleanup directly after each `call` instruction. I can see that doing one cleanup in the end is more optimal, but I wasn't expecting that with disabled optimizations.

Comment: @PeterCordes according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Microsoft_fastcall), `__fastcall` is another ignored convention on x64. I cannot find a name for the x64 convention tho.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-software-conventions?view=vs-2019 says "... x64 uses the `__fastcall` calling convention ..."  and "The `__fastcall` convention uses registers for the first four arguments and the stack frame to pass additional arguments".  Also, I tested MSVC on Godbolt, and `__fastcall` *does* override the `-Gv` default of `__vectorcall`.  https://godbolt.org/z/GFrwKM.

Comment: I guess nobody updated Wikipedia after the creation of `__vectorcall`; at first there was only one x64 convention so that statement was true, but MSVC realized it sucked too much for vector funcs so they now have 2 named conversions.  Naming the default x64 convention `__fastcall` might have been retroactive, IDK.  Wikipedia might have been thinking that `__fastcall` meant specifically the 32-bit style convention, 2 register args and no shadow space.  It's true that nothing will give you that.