# Examples about function pointer and callback function definition

Tags: c++, callback, function-pointers

I'm learning about callback function in C++ and have some problems in understanding **the initialization of a callback function** such as

`typedef void (CALLBACK *name)(int,int);`

I think it looks very similar to **the declaration of function pointer** like this:

`typedef void (*name)(int,int);`

I have a simple example about how to call a function inside another function using **the declaration of function pointer**. The example converts a `string` to `int` and compare with anoter `int`. Then tells which one is bigger:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int StrToInt(char* inputchar)    //converting function
{
    int outputint;
    outputint = atoi(inputchar);
    return outputint;
}

typedef int(*p)(char*);   //declare function pointer

void IntCompare(p FuncP, char* inputchar, int b)    //comparing function
{
    int a;
    a = FuncP(inputchar);    //call converting function using function pointer

    if (a<b)
    {
        printf("%d is bigger\n", b);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d is bigger\n", a);
    }
}

void main()
{   
    char* StrNum = "1234";
    p FuncP;     //creat a function pointer
    FuncP = StrToInt;     //point to converting function
    IntCompare(FuncP, StrNum, 21);
}
```

What I'm asking is:

Could somebody give me a similar example about how to use `typedef void (CALLBACK *name)(int,int);`? Please help me understand when and how to use it. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: A callback function is a function which shall be registered somewhere for later call (back). The registration of a callback function is usually done via a function pointer. The `CALLBACK` in your sample looks somehow specific. I guess it is a macro - a placeholder for something system specific which may vary from system to system. (It might provide a [calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention).) It might be even the case, that macro `CALLBACK` expands on certain systems to nothing. Hard to say without more context. Where did you find it?

Comment: Are you asking why when and how to use a function that takes two int arguments and returns nothing? It likely has some side effect. Or are you asking what is that CALLBACK? It likely is macro potentially expanding to some platform specific keyword like __fastcall.

Comment: Hi @ÖöTiib function with two int arguments are just an example. And yes, I want to know what is that CALLBACK and may be an easy example about it.

Comment: CALLBACK looks like a macro. Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530504/what-does-a-callback-declaration-in-c-do

Comment: Hi @Scheff. I found it in a description file of a C++ DLL. The original arguments are simplified to two `int` arguments in the post.

Comment: @Scheff. Is the function `StrToInt()` in my post a callback function? If it is, why I could use it inside another function `IntCompare()` without registration?

Comment: Any regular function might be used as callback function if it matches the required signature (aka argument number and types, return type, and (in special cases) the calling convention). Callback function does not mean that the function has to be anything special. If it is registered anywhere for call back it becomes a callback function for it. Beside of this, it may still be used in direct function calls. I just found this Wikipedia link: [Callback (computer programming)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)). Wikipedia seems to know rather everything... ;-)

Comment: @Scheff Really appreciate your help. I'll read all these docs.

Comment: note [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), which might be interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CALLBACK` is macro. It relates to callback functions but it's not the same. You can start looking at implementation of callback functions in C.

[`qsort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/) for example uses this technique. `qsort` is a single function which can sort any array. But you have to tell `qsort` how to compare different data types. That's done by passing a function pointer to `qsort`.

```
int compare_int(const void * a, const void * b)
{
  return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}

int compare_string(const void * a, const void * b) 
{
    const char *pa = *(const char**)a;
    const char *pb = *(const char**)b;
    return strcmp(pa, pb);
}

int main ()
{
  int int_array[] = { 3, 2, 1 };
  int count = sizeof(int_array) / sizeof(int);
  qsort(int_array, count, sizeof(int), compare_int);

  const char *string_array[] = { "234","123","456" };
  count = sizeof(string_array) / sizeof(char*);
  qsort(string_array, count, sizeof(char*), compare_string);

  return 0;
}
```

Of course in C++ we use `std::sort`, which uses templates instead.

But we still need to pass functions in C++. See for example, the implementation of [`for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each)

```
template<class InputIt, class UnaryFunction>
UnaryFunction for_each(InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryFunction f)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        f(*first);
    }
    return f;
}
```

Usage:

```
std::vector<int> nums{ 3, 4, 2, 8, 15, 267 };
auto print = [](const int& n) { std::cout << " " << n; };
std::for_each(nums.begin(), nums.end(), print);
std::cout << '\n';
```

Comment: Ps, I am assuming you are familiar with lambda functions. If not, you can replace `auto print = [](const int& n)` with a standard function like `void print(const int n){cout << n << endl;}`